# PyQt.QtSql - get database connection fail informations

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt

**Python 3 - PyQt4 - Qgis 2.14**

I need to display message when my connection is success or fail with **PyQt4.QtSql**.

How retrieve message after `db.connect()` ?

**Here is my code :**

```
def testConnect(self):    
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
        db.setDatabaseName(str(dlg.txt_db.text()))
        db.setUserName(str(dlg.txt_user.text()))
        db.setPassword(str(dlg.txt_psw.text()))
        db.setPort(int(dlg.txt_port.text())) # int entry
        #db.open() - suggest to remove it
        if not db.open():
            msg.setText("Connection failed !")
            retval = msg.exec_()
        else:
            msg.setText("Connection success !")
            retval = msg.exec_()
```

Where is information to change :

> msg.setText("Connection failed !")

by real failed connection information from PyQ4.QtSql and debug ?

Comment: don't need the first `db.open()` and for show the error information can be retrieved using lastError() `db.lastError().text()`

Comment: You suggest me to remove  db.open() as my question update ? How connection db is realize so ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 3?

Comment: yes, Francisco Raga had already share correct answere.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code using your example. **open()** the database in a conditionals make the connection using the current connection values.

If the connection is successfully show *"Connection success !"* but if is failed show the last error that occurred on the database.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *

def testConnect():
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL","Test")
    db.setDatabaseName("postgres")
    db.setUserName("postgres")
    db.setPassword("postgres")
    db.setPort(5432)
    if db.open():
        msg.setText("Connection success !")
    else:
        msg.setText("Connection failed !"+db.lastError().text())
    retval = msg.exec_()
```

I hope it helps you